# How do I force Wikipedia to HTTP, since their HTTPS is broken?

Tags: wikipedia, https

Is there a way to force Wikipedia to HTTP?

I'm using [Lynx](http://mdoc.su/o52/lynx.1), but it says that the certificate is expired.  (Since my clock is correct, it's probably one of the intermediary or root certificates on my system that has reached its expiration date.)

Being needlessly forced into HTTPS is very annoying; I don't need HTTPS; how do I read Wikipedia over HTTP?

```
$ lynx -dump en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenBSD
Looking up en.wikipedia.org
Making HTTP connection to en.wikipedia.org
Sending HTTP request.
HTTP request sent; waiting for response.
HTTP/1.1 301 TLS Redirect
Data transfer complete
HTTP/1.1 301 TLS Redirect
Using https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenBSD
Looking up en.wikipedia.org
Making HTTPS connection to en.wikipedia.org
SSL callback:certificate has expired, preverify_ok=0, ssl_okay=0
Retrying connection without TLS.
Looking up en.wikipedia.org
Making HTTPS connection to en.wikipedia.org
Alert!: Unable to make secure connection to remote host.

lynx: Can't access startfile https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenBSD
```

Comment: In order to do this, Wikipedia themselves would need to have built in some kind of "backdoor" to allow HTTP traffic - but I can't think of any reason why _they_ would want to do this?

Comment: @w3d, "backdoor"?  To access public information, which is already publicly available?  Really, a "backdoor"?  (Or, is it rather "public" information, "publicly" available?)

Comment: What I mean is, that once a site has implemented a site-wide redirection to HTTPS, _they_ would need to implement some kind of exception (a "backdoor") to allow non-HTTPS traffic through. This isn't something an end user should be able to control, so I would doubt that there is a solution unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

As of June 2015, HTTPS is *required* to view the English Wikipedia, along with several other language versions of Wikipedia. According to Wikimedia, browsing over HTTP is no longer possible.

See [Wikimedia's page on HTTPS](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/HTTPS) for more information.